Coredata performBackgroundTask can't get the update in main context
I'm trying to use background context to update NSManagedObject(User), and get the updates in main viewContext.
Following the : Apple's documentation
Here's is the code:
func testUpdateUser() throws {

    //Step 1. Create User in mainViewContext
    let tim = userStore?.fetchUser(userName: "Tim")
    XCTAssertNotNil(tim)

    //Step 2. Update user's attribute in background context

    let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.parent = persistentContainer.viewContext
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "updateUser") 
    context.performAndWait{
        do {
            guard let user = try context.existingObject(with: tim!.objectID) as? User else {
                return
            }
            user.foo = "foo"
            context.performAndWait {
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        persistentContainer.viewContext.performAndWait {
            try? persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        }
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    //Step 3. assert it works.
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2.0)
    XCTAssertEqual(Tim?.foo, "foo") //Passed
}

I have set up
        persistentContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true


The code works well.
Then I want to use performBackgroundTask to make the same function:
func testUpdateUserBackgroundTask() throws {
        
     //Step 1. Create User and fetch in mainViewContext
     let tim = userStore?.fetchUser(userName: "Tim")
     XCTAssertNotNil(tim)

     //Step 2. Update user's attribute in background context

      let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "updateUser")

      persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask({ context in
            do {
                guard let user = try context.existingObject(with: tim!.objectID) as? User else {
                    return
                }
                user.foo = "foo"
                context.performAndWait {
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            expectation.fulfill()
        })
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2.0)
        XCTAssertEqual(tim?.foo, "foo") // NOT PASS!
    }

I'm not quite sure why performBackgroundTask doesn't works as expected. As I have set persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true, the background context should be in same coordinator as main viewContext, that is, the changes should be automatically merge to main context. Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Few things...

Drop the performAndWait - You're already in the new background context thread - there is no need for that.
Nothing is updating the tim object. It might be a fault but it shouldn't be updated automatically.

So either you use a NSFetchedResultsController to update tim OR (faster and better approach for tests) after the save is done - move back to the main thread and re-fetch the object.
something like this:
func testUpdateUserBackgroundTask() throws {
    
 //Step 1. Create User and fetch in mainViewContext
 let tim = userStore?.fetchUser(userName: "Tim")
 XCTAssertNotNil(tim)

 //Step 2. Update user's attribute in background context

  let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "updateUser")

  persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask({ context in
        do {
            guard let user = try context.existingObject(with: tim!.objectID) as? User else {
                return
            }
            user.foo = "foo"
            do { try context.save()
            } catch { XCTFail(error) }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let tim = userStore?.fetchUser(userName: "Tim")
                XCTAssertNotNil(tim)
                XCTAssertEqual(tim?.foo, "foo") // NOT PASS!
            }

            expectation.fulfill()
    })

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2.0)
}

